# How to select all elements in the list box using Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I can select a single element present in the list box of the website using this,

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("ID"))
```

and can be selected using select_by_visible_text method but how can we select all the items in the list box(not a combo box/drop down box)  if we select one item other will be deselected how to select all the items in Python

Answer some how I figured it out:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("ddlamc"))
count = 0
for o in select.options:
    print(o.text)
    if(count>1):
        select.select_by_visible_text(o.text)
    browser.save_screenshot("phase%d.png"%count)
    count+=1
```

Comment: Is it a multi select dropdown? if it is then repeated calls to select_by_,,,,, will select the options.

Comment: If you cannot select two values in select manually, then using selenium also you cannot select all values,because its html/js property by which the select is declared in a drop-down list that allows multiple selections

Comment: @thebadguy, yes I can select 2 or more values by holding ctrl button and selecting, the website is poor instead of check buttons they've done something like this!

Comment: Can you add html of it